# NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to run Tycho-built Eclipse RCP application under Linux/Mac OS

Tags: cross-platform, eclipse-rcp, classnotfoundexception, tycho, target-platform

I'm developing a cross-platform RCP application in Win 7 (64bit), Indigo/Java 1.6, building the product with Tycho.

While the application runs fine from the Run Configuration within eclipse, and the Win x_86_64 build runs fine as well, I get the following errors on both xubuntu (with OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime (1.6.0_24) and Mac OS X (1.6.0_35).

The error (on Linux) looks like this (running `java myprogram`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myprogram
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myprogram
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: myprogram. Program will exit.
```

I'm sure I've come across this before, and I think it was something stupid (this has happened on Windows before AFAIK, and re-installing Java fixed it for some reason). In this case, however, I think it must be to do with the build/target platform/Tycho setup.

The part of my parent POM responsible for the cross-platform build looks unsuspicious enough:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
        <!-- configure the p2 target environments for multi-platform build -->
        <environments>

          <environment>
            <os>linux</os>
            <ws>gtk</ws>
            <arch>x86</arch>
          </environment>
          <environment>
            <os>linux</os>
            <ws>gtk</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
          <environment>
            <os>win32</os>
            <ws>win32</ws>
            <arch>x86</arch>
          </environment>

          <environment>
            <os>win32</os>
            <ws>win32</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
          <environment>
            <os>macosx</os>
            <ws>cocoa</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
        </environments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this might not work?
Many thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error messages with `java myprogram -X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you run an Eclipse RCP application.

You either need to launch it with the appropriate native launcher, or with a `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_(yourVersion).jar` (see [this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html)) and probably further arguments to select your [application](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_runtime_applications.html).

Also, you need to make sure that you have the bundles in your application that Equinox needs to start up. You can do this by including the feature `org.eclipse.rcp` in you product.

Comment: Thanks, the `java -jar` version works perfectly on both OSs. Re native launchers: I was hoping that *Tycho* would create these for me. I've read up about them, but all the posts, etc. I've read mention the *Delta Pack* as part of the deal, whereas I thought it wouldn't be necessary anymore to include it anymore because (if I remember correctly) the necessary plugins would all be available in the eclipse p2... Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Also, the native launchers do exist, but when I double-click on the Linux one in Finder, nothing happens. `myprogram.app` in Mac OS X doesn't do anything either. I guess they're badly configured (i.e., not configured at all) in my Product Configuration.

Comment: The native launchers do work if you have everything configured correctly - see [this tutorial](https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo) for a working example. Tycho needs the `org.eclipse.equinox.executable` feature (aka "delta pack"), but it usually pulls it automatically out of the Eclipse release train repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll have a good look at the setup there, as well as listening closely to your upcoming tutorial at EclipseCon Europe :).